# accesing text field on stage from external as class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to acces the textfield I have placed on the stage, with instance name `texx`  from an external as3 file with code.

```
package src 
{   

    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Global 
    {
        public static var _stage:Stage;
        public static var r:MovieClip = MovieClip(root);

        }

        public function Global()
        {
                r.texx.text = "some text"

        }

    }

}
```

as you guessed it is not displaying the text i want. I searched high and low but couldn't find on how to access stage objects from external classes that are inside a package. any help would be appreciated

Comment: it displays error " acces of undefined property root"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding the text field as a class object from inside a movie clip, just created, gave the movie clip (inside which is the text field tex) class name `src.texter`  then in as class

```
package src 
{   

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import src.texter;

public class Global
{
    public var texxx:texter = new texter;


    public function Global()

        {
                    addChild(texxx);
            texxx.x = 336;
            texxx.y = 330;
            texxx.tex.text = "some text";

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access stage instance from non display class, Stage hasn't static getter to its instance. The only way is to set the property `stage` from a view class, for example:

```
package src 
{   

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Global
{
    private static var _stage:Stage;

    public static function set stage(value:Stage):void 
    {
        if(stage != value)
        {
            _stage = value;
            init();
        }
    }
    public static function get stage():Stage 
    {
        return _stage;
    }

    private static function init():void
    {
        stage.texx.text = "some text";
    }
}
}
```

and code in the document class :

```
Global.stage = stage;
```

The same if for `root`.

Comment: unfortunatelly I don't have Main class that has access to the stage reference, every as file is in the same directory and package.

Comment: so where do I declare this Global.stage = stage; ? I added the rest of the script in the as file as you wrote but it diplays the error  "acces of undefined property texx"